# How to remove https

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

In my website there are only few pages are using https. I don't know where its coming from but I have to remove those https. How can I achieve.

My current .htaccess setting

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /indiv/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /indiv/index.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/indiv/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^indiv/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/indiv/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /indiv/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: But page not loading. it says 
"www.yourdomain.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Completely clear your browser cache before testing this. Also what is your web server? Is `%{HTTPS}` working for you otherwise?

Comment: I cleared browser cache, still I have the problem, before https working normally. what you mean webserver?

Comment: What is the web server version that is serving requests on your host? It might be apache or cloud fare or something else.

Comment: Its apache web server

Comment: I've tested same rules on my Apache installation and there is no redirect loop so it is definitely some setup issue on your host/web server.